# How to use helm environment variables in a frontend

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, frontend, kubernetes-helm

I'm developing a frontend which will be hosted in AKS with Helm. Now I want to make use of Helm for the environment variables, but I'm struggling with how to do it. I currently have my environment variables in a values.yaml file and I'm loading them into my deployment chart. Now Ideally these environment variables would be loaded into a json format which will be created by Helm. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: My be looking for this? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/  . You can substitute the , `value` of the env variable in yaml from helm `values.yaml` file

Comment: What have you set up so far?  If you were running this outside a container; you had run `npm build` and were serving the front-end; how would you inject these configuration values without rebuilding the application?